P-tree onNodeUnselect should reselect the node, avoid default behaviour primeng
I am using Prime ng tree for tree render in my application.
Usecase: Simply, when node is selected again (onNodeUnselect) , I want the node to be still considered as selected. So, I can call the method of NodeSelect again and retrieve the fresh data for the node.
<p-tree
        [value]="getValidTreeNodeItems(treeObj?.treeData)"
        selectionMode="single"
        (onNodeSelect)="onNodeSelect($event)"
        (onNodeUnselect)="preventUnselect($event)" > ....
//prevent 
 preventUnselect(event: any) {
        event.originalEvent.preventDefault(); //doesn't work
        event.originalEvent.stopPropagation(); //doesn't work either

thus the node is considered unselected, and all the selection classes are removed too.
I tried the way of applying classes (like p-highlight) to the node which just got unselected to make it look selected, but this leads to maintaining another logical stuff to assign and remove the classes, which I want to avoid.
Thanks in advance for the help.

I tried this, it never worked
preventUnselect(event: any){
        this.onNodeSelect(event)
    }

Then I realised maybe it's about the time delay. So I tried the setTimeout, though there seems a little delay but it gets reselected then.
preventUnselect(event: any){
        setTimeout(() => {
        this.onNodeSelect(event)
        }, 0);
    }

